# The limit of sequence $(\frac{n \sin(2n)}{n^2 + \cos(n) + 4})$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I have trouble evaluating the limit of the sequence $(\frac{n \sin(2n)}{n^2 + \cos(n) + 4})$. Could anyone help me? Thank you!

Comment: No time to answer properly: the only thing that matters is $n$ on top and $n^2$ on the bottom. Thus the limit is the same as the limit of $n/n^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment pretty much says everything you need, anyway, here is an alternative approach:
$$0 \le \Big|\frac{n\sin(2n)}{n^2 + \cos(n) + 4}\Big| \le \Big|\frac{n \cdot 1}{n^2 -1 + 4}\Big| = \frac{n}{n^2 + 3} \le \frac{n}{n^2} = \frac{1}{n} \to 0$$

Conclude with the squeeze theorem.

Comment: Thank you very much. But one more thing that need to be clarified in this proof is that in order to use the squeeze theorem, we need to have both side converges to 0 when $n > N$. I think it might be a better if we have $\frac{-1*n}{n^2 +1 + 4} \le \frac{n \sin (2n)}{n^2 + \cos (n) +4} \le \frac{1*n}{n^2 - 1 + 4}$

Comment: well, the chain of inequalities starts with 0 since 0 converges to 0 trivially. :)